# Normal Form Theorem for Skew Symmetric Forms

Tags: symplectic-linear-algebra

This is a theorem mentioned in Hansjorg Geiges' Symplectic Geometry book while proving Darboux's theorem for local realisation of a contact form on a manifold $M^{2n+1}$ (see $\S2.5.1$ p.67) I haven't seen this theorem in any textbook or on the net. Could anyone state it for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps it's referring to the result that for any nonsingular skew-symmetric form on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ over any field, there is a basis $e_1, ..., e_n, f_1, ..., f_n$ of $V$ such that $\langle e_i, f_i \rangle = 1$, $\langle f_i, e_i \rangle = -1$, and all other pairings between basis vectors are 0.

Comment: So to prove this, I start with a symplectic basis for the kernel of $\alpha$ at $p$ (we can find one) and then if we find $z$ such that $d\alpha(z,x)=0$ for all $x$ in the kernel then we are sure $i_zd\alpha\equiv0$, for anyway $d\alpha(z,z)=0$ and $z$ together with $\ker\alpha$ span the vector space.
So here $z$ lies in a 1-d space and we can scale to ensure $\alpha(z)=1$. Is this a legitimate way to go about the proof?

Comment: Can you explain your notation more?  What is $i_z$? What is a symplectic basis?  I would have assumed a symplectic basis was the type of basis described in the theorem I quoted above, but if you're trying to prove this theorem, then you can't start with such a basis...

Comment: Oh sorry
$i_z\omega$ for a 2-form $\omega$ is defined as $i_z\omega(x)=\omega(z,x)$
and yes indeed, a symplectic basis is one you described in your answer.

Comment: @Host-website-on-iPage You can find a proof in the wonderful linear algebra book of Kostrikin and Manin, in [section 3.3](https://books.google.fr/books?id=3TZETTPyOQ0C&lpg=PP1&pg=PA102) combined with [section 2.10](https://books.google.fr/books?id=3TZETTPyOQ0C&lpg=PP1&pg=PA100).